# How to provide resource files to a custom beamer template

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, r-package

*First things first, it is not easy to create a reproducible example since my question is related to building a package that provides a custom knitr format. I hope I can make my problem clear and am interested in your ideas how to solve this best.*

**The problem**

I am writing a R package containing a custom knitr format (formatted beamer slides to be precise).
In these beamer slides I include a `*.sty` tex file using the command

```
\input{$resource$/thefile.sty}
```

where `$resources$` is a pandoc variable which I provide through my custom format function. This will resolve to

```
\input{/path/to/packagelibrary/package/resources/thefile.sty}
```

When installing the package, creating a new RMD document from my template and knitting it, the `*.sty` is indeed found within the installed package directory. But LaTeX throws the warning

> Output created: Untitled.pdf Warning message: LaTeX Warning(s):
>   You have requested package `', but the package provides `thefile.sty'

I know this is just a warning, but if possible I would like to eliminate these too. And I say ***these***, because in the end I have multiple files that are located within the `inst/rmarkdown/templates/mytemplate/resources/` folder.

I thought about copying those resources into the intermediates folder so that they are deleted afterwards. But I am not sure if that is possible or even desirable.

I am open for any suggestions on how to tackle this.

Comment: Don't LaTeX style files usually start with `\ProvidesPackage`?  It sounds as though your `thefile.sty` has something like that, but you are loading it using `\input` instead of `\usepackage`.  Would `\usepackage{$resource$/thefile.sty}` work?

Comment: Unfortunately this makes no difference. The warnings still arise. I read somewhere this has to do with how LaTeX resolves file paths but could not find more details on that.

Comment: The command inside the `.sty`file is `\ProvidesPackage{myfile.sty}`. That is the point I guess, there is no path at all since usually these files are in the local texmf tree.

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer It should be `\ProvidesPackage{thefile}` (without `.sty`). I Would suggest to install your .sty file in a location where it can automatically be found by tex (e.g. your texmf tree) so you don't have to worry about any paths.

Comment: Again, this does not change a thing. And I am asking this because I discard the option of installing the sty files to the local texmf tree since I want to distribute the package (the custom format) to persons not knowing how to install sty files to local texmf trees. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you put the package online somewhere maybe we could experiment with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to do it, but it looks a little fragile.

As this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124013 shows, including a path in the `\usepackage{}` call basically exploits a failure in error checking.  The warning you're seeing in your log is by design.

Here's a way around this problem, which might work for you.  Put this code into the `.tex` file before calling LaTeX, and it will look for your style file in the right place without giving a warning:

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{$resource$/}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{thefile}
```

and in `thefile.sty` include

```
\ProvidesPackage{thefile}
```

(Notice you don't include the `.sty` extension in either place.)

I say this is a little fragile, because some other part of the code might be playing with `\input@path`.  You can have more than one path in there, but my TeX knowledge isn't deep enough to know how to say to add an extra path to the existing one.   All I can say is that if you start with the definition `{{a}}`, you want to end up with the definition `{{$resource$/}{a}}`.

Comment: This works. It might probably be not the intended way but I will use it. I do not understand why including packages using an absolute path is not intended in the first place. Anyhow, thanks.